# PHP CLI and Constants

Tags: php, constants, command-line-interface

What is wrong with my code:

```
if(!defined(FILE_ROOT_PATH)){
    define('FILE_ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
echo 'Path: '.FILE_ROOT_PATH;
```

when run from CLI it gives:

> Use of undefined constant FILE_ROOT_PATH - assumed 'FILE_ROOT_PATH' in ...

Can't I use constants on CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the string you pass to `defined()`.

```
if(!defined('FILE_ROOT_PATH')){
    define('FILE_ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
echo 'Path: '.FILE_ROOT_PATH;
```

Otherwise, you're trying to reference the constant before it exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
if(!defined(FILE_ROOT_PATH)){
```

[defined()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) requires a *string* with the constant's name.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!defined('FILE_ROOT_PATH')){
define('FILE_ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
echo 'Path: '.FILE_ROOT_PATH;
```